# Socket error: WebSocketException: Connection to 'http://192.168.42.48:8000/api/users/?EIO=4&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: laravel, flutter, websocket

I have applied my local web socket Api in flutter app it throws exception, tried a lot but can't find any solution,
Api is in Laravel, on Laravel side I also use Socket.io package and Laravel-echo , here is my flutter connection code

```
 void connectToSocket() {
    try {
      /// You can change your localhost [IPV4] here.
      String localhostIp = '192.168.42.48';
      String socketUrl = 'http://$localhostIp:8000';
      String apiUrl = 'http://$localhostIp:8000/api/users';
      String socketPath = apiUrl.replaceAll(socketUrl, '');

      socket = IO.io(
        socketUrl,
        <String, dynamic>{
          'transports': ['websocket'],
          'autoConnect': false,
          'path': socketPath,
          'Connection': 'Upgrade',
          'Upgrade': 'websocket',
          'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '4.6.2',
          'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'client_max_window_bits',
        },
      );

      socket!.onConnect((_) {
        log('Connected to socket!');
      });

      socket!.onError((error) {
        log('Socket error: $error');
      });

      socket!.on('newMessage', (data) {
        log('New message: $data');
      });

      socket!.connect();
    } catch (e) {
      log('Error connecting to socket: $e');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the socket url need to be like this: ws://192.168.42.48:{somePort}/api/users, not http...